# Duplicating enemies with AI

Tags: flash, variables, actionscript-2

I am working on a flash game in which you fight enemies. I did the whole AI for an enemie I called slime. Now I would like to put multiple of this enemy on the scene and I wondered if I had to duplicate all the code, for example slime1 slime2 etc.

```
if ((img_background.BackGround.wall).hitTest(slime._x + radius, slime._y,true )) { // When the slime hits a right wall
    slime._x -= 8
}

if ((img_background.BackGround.wall).hitTest(slime._x, slime._y + radius, true)) {
    slime._y -= 8;
}
if ((img_background.BackGround.wall).hitTest(slime._x, slime._y - radius, true)) {
    slime._y += 8;
}
if ((img_background.BackGround.wall).hitTest(slime._x - radius, slime._y, true)) {
    slime._x += 8;
}

if ((img_background.BackGround.wall).hitTest(slime._x)){
    SLIwalltouch = 1
}else{
    SLIwalltouch = 0
}
```

Can I assign a variable with multiple value and do something like: "slime" + numberofslimes .....
I am new to this and I need help. Thanks.

Note: I am using flash actionscript 2.0

Comment: is slime a movie clip ?

Answer (score 0):

use a function to wrap the code and the parameter will be any movieclip you want. first, let's prepare a function that will check the hit-test against "target". let's call it checkTouch, for example

```
    function checkTouch(target){
      // When the slime hits a right wall
      if ((img_background.BackGround.wall).hitTest(target._x + radius, target._y,true )){ 
        target._x -= 8
      }
      if ((img_background.BackGround.wall).hitTest(target._x, target._y + radius, true)) {
        target._y -= 8;
      }
      if ((img_background.BackGround.wall).hitTest(target._x, target._y - radius, true)) {
        target._y += 8;
      }
      if ((img_background.BackGround.wall).hitTest(target._x - radius, target._y, true)) {
        target._x += 8;
      }

      if ((img_background.BackGround.wall).hitTest(target._x)){
        SLIwalltouch = 1
      }else{
        SLIwalltouch = 0
      }
    }
```

notice that i've replaced all the occurrences of "slime" with "target". at this point, you can call the function with any movieclip you like and it will check that movieclip for the hit.

to make the code do exactly the same as yours, just add this:

```
    checkTouch(slime);
```

now this should be a hint on how to check more objects. if you have, let's say, enemies called "slime", "slime2", "hellhound" and "dragon", you could do

```
    checkTouch(slime);
    checkTouch(slime2);
    checkTouch(hellhound);
    checkTouch(dragon);
```

however, if you end up having more enemies it will be much more useful to add the enemies into an array and then apply the function to them in a loop:

```
    var all_enemies=[slime, slime2, hellhound, mushroom, ..., enemyN];

    for(enemy in all_enemies){
      checkTouch(enemy);
    }
```

note that in order to function, the enemies must be present on stage before you can declare then in the array like this.

if you don't feel like writing all the enemies in the array out and know the exact number of the enemies you'll have- you can make use of flash's ability to construct the movieclip names.

it goes like this, name all your enemies like enemy1, enemy2, enemy3, ...
and then make the for loop look like this:

```
    for(i=0; i<numberofenemies; i++){ //replace numberofenemies with the number of enemies
      checkTouch(this["enemy"+i]);
    }
```